# How to record the Requests for Angular JS and React JS based application using JMeter

Tags: reactjs, angularjs, performance-testing, jmeter-5.0

As whwn I have recorded the requests are not visible
How to create test case for Performance testing on Angular Js and React JS based application

As whwn I have recorded the requests are not visible

Answer (score 0):

As per [JMeter project main page](https://jmeter.apache.org/):

> JMeter is not a browser, it works at protocol level. As far as web-services and remote services are concerned, JMeter looks like a browser (or rather, multiple browsers); however JMeter does not perform all the actions supported by browsers. **In particular, JMeter does not execute the Javascript found in HTML pages.** Nor does it render the HTML pages as a browser does (it's possible to view the response as HTML etc., but the timings are not included in any samples, and only one sample in one thread is ever displayed at a time).

Assuming above:

- JMeter won't execute any JavaScript hence it won't generate any traffic connected with [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp) requests
- If JavaScript call doesn't generate a [HTTP Request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods) - you don't need to worry about it as it runs only on the **client side**

If JMeter doesn't record anything - first of all check [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) for any suspicious entries. The most common reasons are:

- people forget to import JMeter's certificate into their browser, see **HTTPS recording and certificates** chapter of [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) user manual entry for more details
- people fail to configure browser properly, i.e. Firefox cannot record local traffic unless you set [`network.proxy.allow_hijacking_localhost` property](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1535581) to `true`

Also be aware of an alternative way of recording a JMeter test: [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732579-The-BlazeMeter-Chrome-Extension-Record-JMeter-Selenium-or-Synchronized-JMeter-and-Selenium). In this case you don't need to worry about proxies and certificates, just follow your test scenario steps in your browser and in the end you will be able to export the recorded script in form of JMeter [.jmx test plan](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JmxTestPlan)